# Pass variable in Json payload?

Tags: python, json, post

I have the following code:

```
import requests
import time

orderID = time.strftime("%#d%m%y") + str(randint(10, 99))
payload = '{ "id": 62345, "shippingCharge": 0.0, "giftCharge": 0.0, "amountDue": 13000.0}'
url = "test.com/v1/%s".format(orderID)
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
r = s.post(url , payload, auth=('test01', 'test01'))
```

I want to pass the variable `orderID` in the following:

1. as the value for `id` field in the JSON payload.
2. After `v1` in the URL string

Please help me out.

Comment: Please post your actual code. This is not valid

Comment: edit the question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why do you keep posting code in the comments? Please fix the code in your question!

Comment: Code relating to your question has to go into the body of the question itself. And it needs to be formatted properly because correct indentation is _vital_ in Python.

Answer (score 0):

1) as the value for id field in the JSON payload.

```
 orderID = time.strftime("%#d%m%y") + str(randint(10, 99)) 
 payload = '{ "id": '+ str(orderID) +', "shippingCharge": 0.0, "giftCharge": 0.0, 
"amountDue": 13000.0}'
```

2) After v1 in the URL string

The code you have given is correct for your use case.

Comment: Getting this error after using the above mentioned code

Comment: File "saveOrder.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(r.json())
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 866, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "D:\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

Comment: File "D:\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
import requests
from random import randint
import time

orderID = time.strftime("%#d%m%y") + str(randint(10, 99))
payload = ('{ "id": ' + str(orderID) + ', "shippingCharge": 0.0, "giftCharge": 0.0, '
           '"amountDue": 13000.0}')
url = "test.com/v1/{}".format(orderID)
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
r = s.post(url , payload, auth=('test01', 'test01'))
```

Comment: Try using `r = s.post(url, data=payload, auth=('test01', 'test01'))` as the last line. If that doesn't work try `r = s.post(url, json=payload, auth=('test01', 'test01'))`.

Comment: I am using the following statement r = s.post(url, json=payload, auth=('test01', 'test01')) followed by - print(r.json())

Comment: Following is the error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "saveOrder.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(r.json())

Comment: File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 866, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "D:\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "D:\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)